# Provider not updating when doing, Navigator.pop(context) in flutter

Tags: flutter, provider

Here I am using provider package for state management.
I have a SpeedDial widget in the floatingActionButton. And whenever I add something in the list  `mainGoalList` by using speedDial and do `Navigator.pop(context);`  it does go back to the page but does not update the list.

**SpeedDial**

```
        SpeedDialChild(
                  child: Icon(Icons.book),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  label: 'Add Notes',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                        context: context,
                        isScrollControlled: true,
                        builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                        .viewInsets
                                        .bottom),
                                child: AddNotes(),
                              ),
                            ));
                  }),
```

**AddNote**

```
          Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_actcontroller.text == null) {
                  print("Cannot add null topic");
                } else {
                  addingTheNotes();
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
              child: Text("Add"),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          )
```

**Adding the notes**

```
  addingTheNotes() {
    theDataProvider.ourAllnotes.add(
      TodaysNoteClass(
        note: _actcontroller.text,
        dateTime: theDataProvider.notesChoosenDate,
        status: false,
      ),
    );
    theDataProvider.showingTheTodaysList();
  }
```

**Here is the change notifier**

```
  List<TodaysNoteClass> _ourAllnotes = [];
  List<TodaysNoteClass> get ourAllnotes => _ourAllnotes;
  set ourAllnotes(List<TodaysNoteClass> val) {
    _ourAllnotes = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

**Consumer class, this is where I am showing the notes**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'homePage';
  final String todaysDate =
      DateFormat('d MMMM').format(DateTime.now()).toLowerCase();
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var theDataProvider;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    theDataProvider = Provider.of<TheData>(context, listen: false);

    return Consumer<TheData>(
      builder: (context, value, child) => SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 120,
                child: TodaysNote(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**And this is the TodaysNote class**

```
class TodaysNote extends StatefulWidget {
  TodaysNote({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  bool boxChecked = false;
  @override
  _TodaysNoteState createState() => _TodaysNoteState();
}

class _TodaysNoteState extends State<TodaysNote> {
  var theDataProvider;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    theDataProvider = Provider.of<TheData>(context, listen: false);

    return Consumer<TheData>(
      builder: (context, value, child) => Container(
        child: theDataProvider.showingTheTodaysList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But now when I go to another screen and then come to the previous screen. I see the updated list.
I have wrapped the main file with provider, wrapped the files with consumer but did not work.
What might be the reason behind this?

Comment: can you share me some code of addingTheNotes()

Comment: Where is ChangeNotifierProvider?

Comment: please have a look to the updated question

Comment: Have you try using Selector ?

Comment: not yet. I have not used that before.

Comment: try to use StatefulWidget class in case you are using stateless

Comment: i am using stateful widget

Comment: @AmanChaudhary Kindly share the `Consumer` widget and the class where you provider your `provider`

Comment: please have a look at the updated question @AbdulrahmanFalyoun

Comment: Have you solved your problem 
Please post it i am facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => SecondPage()), ).then((value) => setState(() {}));